# How can a control receive mouse events after the mouse is dragged beyond its borders?

Tags: delphi, mouse, delphi-xe2, windows-messages

I'm creating a custom control which recognizes when the mouse is dragging, specifically using messages `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, `WM_LBUTTONUP`, and `WM_MOUSEMOVE`. When the mouse goes down, I capture the position on the control, and then when the mouse moves, if the left mouse button is down, I do more handling (calculating between starting and ending points).

The problem is, I'm expecting the mouse to go out of the control, and even out of the form, but when the mouse leaves the control, it no longer captures mouse events. Is there a way I can handle specifically the `WM_MOUSEMOVE` and `WM_LBUTTONUP` messages without the mouse being over the control?

Comment: It would be awesome if the VCL `TMouse` had events such as `OnButtonDown`, `OnButtonUp`, and `OnMove`

Comment: Adding to my comment above, I have created my own mouse hook based off the accepted answer. With this hook, you can create multiple instances of `TJDMouse` wherever needed, and assign different Event Handlers as necessary. Then, when the hook gets mouse messages, it iterates through those `TJDMouse` instances and triggers events as necessary. This is separate from the original `TMouse` in the sense that 1) you can create multiple instances, and 2) mouse events are global, not specific to any control. See my extra answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Releasecapture will work for Wincontrols, an other way could be a Mousehook. That's just a demo ....

```
unit MouseHook;
// 2012 by Thomas Wassermann
interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs;

type

  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation

var
  HookHandle: Cardinal;

Type
  tagMSLLHOOKSTRUCT = record
    POINT: TPoint;
    mouseData: DWORD;
    flags: DWORD;
    time: DWORD;
    dwExtraInfo: DWORD;
  end;
  TMSLLHOOKSTRUCT = tagMSLLHOOKSTRUCT;
  PMSLLHOOKSTRUCT = ^TMSLLHOOKSTRUCT;

{$R *.dfm}

function LowLevelMouseProc(nCode: Integer; wParam: wParam; lParam: lParam): LRESULT; stdcall;
var
 Delta:Smallint;
begin
  if (nCode >= 0) then
  begin
    Form3.Caption := Format('X: %d  Y: %d ', [PMSLLHOOKSTRUCT(lParam)^.Point.X,  PMSLLHOOKSTRUCT(lParam)^.Point.Y]);
    if wParam = WM_LButtonDOWN then Form3.Caption := Form3.Caption + ' LD';
    if wParam = WM_LButtonUP then Form3.Caption := Form3.Caption + ' LU';
    if wParam = WM_RButtonDOWN then Form3.Caption := Form3.Caption + ' RD';
    if wParam = WM_RButtonUP then Form3.Caption := Form3.Caption + ' RU';
    if wParam =  WM_MOUSEMOVE then Form3.Caption := Form3.Caption + ' Move';
    Delta := PMSLLHOOKSTRUCT(lParam)^.mouseData shr 16;
    if wParam =  WM_MOUSEWHEEL then
          begin

            Form3.Caption := Form3.Caption + ' Wheel ' ;
            if Delta=120 then Form3.Caption := Form3.Caption + ' KLICK'
            else if Delta > 0  then Form3.Caption := Form3.Caption +' UP'
            else if Delta < 0  then Form3.Caption := Form3.Caption +' DOWN'
          end;
    if wParam =  WM_MOUSEHWHEEL then
          begin
            Form3.Caption := Form3.Caption + ' HWheel';
            if Delta=120 then Form3.Caption := Form3.Caption + ' KLICK'
            else if Delta > 0  then Form3.Caption := Form3.Caption +' UP'
            else if Delta < 0  then Form3.Caption := Form3.Caption +' DOWN'

          end;
     Form3.Caption := Form3.Caption +' >> '+ IntToStr(Delta)

  end;
  Result := CallNextHookEx(HookHandle, nCode, wParam, lParam);
end;

function InstallMouseHook: Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
  if HookHandle = 0 then
  begin
    HookHandle := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, @LowLevelMouseProc, hInstance, 0);
    Result := HookHandle <> 0;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  InstallMouseHook;
end;

procedure TForm3.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if HookHandle <> 0 then
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(HookHandle);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Thank you, I got this wrapped beautifully into my own class where I register for event handlers, etc.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `SetCapture/ReleaseCapture` Windows API to continue to get mouse events when the cursor moves outside the control.

Answer (score 3):

I have accepted the answer above, but my final version of this implementation is quite different. I thought I'd share what I came up with, as implementing a unique mouse hook multiple times was a little tricky.

Now the demonstration `bummi` provided was fixed and built-in to the form's unit. I created a new unit and wrapped everything in there. The tricky part was that the function `LowLevelMouseProc` cannot be part of the class. Yet, within this function, it makes a call specific to the hook handle (`Result := CallNextHookEx(HookHandle, nCode, wParam, lParam);`). So what I did was created a bucket (`TList`) where I dump every instance of my mouse object. When this function is called, it iterates through this bucket and triggers the appropriate events of each instance. This model also includes built-in thread-safe protection (untested).

Here's the full unit:

**JD.Mouse.pas**

```
unit JD.Mouse;

interface

uses
  Windows, Classes, SysUtils, Messages, Controls;

type
  TJDMouseButtonPoints = Array[TMouseButton] of TPoint;
  TJDMouseButtonStates = Array[TMouseButton] of Boolean;

  TJDMouse = class(TComponent)
  private
    FOnButtonUp: TMouseEvent;
    FOnMove: TMouseMoveEvent;
    FOnButtonDown: TMouseEvent;
    FButtonPoints: TJDMouseButtonPoints;
    FButtonStates: TJDMouseButtonStates;
    procedure SetCursorPos(const Value: TPoint);
    function GetCursorPos: TPoint;
    procedure DoButtonDown(const IsDown: Boolean; const Button: TMouseButton;
      const Shift: TShiftState; const X, Y: Integer);
    procedure DoMove(const Shift: TShiftState; const X, Y: Integer);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property CursorPos: TPoint read GetCursorPos write SetCursorPos;
    property OnButtonDown: TMouseEvent read FOnButtonDown write FOnButtonDown;
    property OnButtonUp: TMouseEvent read FOnButtonUp write FOnButtonUp;
    property OnMove: TMouseMoveEvent read FOnMove write FOnMove;
  end;

implementation

var
  _Hook: Cardinal;
  _Bucket: TList;
  _Lock: TRTLCriticalSection;

procedure LockMouse;
begin
  EnterCriticalSection(_Lock);
end;

procedure UnlockMouse;
begin
  LeaveCriticalSection(_Lock);
end;

type
  tagMSLLHOOKSTRUCT = record
    POINT: TPoint;
    mouseData: DWORD;
    flags: DWORD;
    time: DWORD;
    dwExtraInfo: DWORD;
  end;
  TMSLLHOOKSTRUCT = tagMSLLHOOKSTRUCT;
  PMSLLHOOKSTRUCT = ^TMSLLHOOKSTRUCT;

function LowLevelMouseProc(nCode: Integer; wParam: wParam; lParam: lParam): LRESULT; stdcall;
var
  X: Integer;
  Delta: Smallint;
  M: TJDMouse;
  P: TPoint;
  Shift: TShiftState;
begin
  if (nCode >= 0) then begin
    LockMouse;
    try
      Delta := PMSLLHOOKSTRUCT(lParam)^.mouseData shr 16;
      try
        for X := 0 to _Bucket.Count - 1 do begin
          try
            M:= TJDMouse(_Bucket[X]);
            P:= Controls.Mouse.CursorPos;
            //Shift:= .....;   //TODO
            case wParam of
              WM_LBUTTONDOWN: begin
                M.DoButtonDown(True, mbLeft, Shift, P.X, P.Y);
              end;
              WM_LBUTTONUP: begin
                M.DoButtonDown(False, mbLeft, Shift, P.X, P.Y);
              end;
              WM_RBUTTONDOWN: begin
                M.DoButtonDown(True, mbRight, Shift, P.X, P.Y);
              end;
              WM_RBUTTONUP: begin
                M.DoButtonDown(False, mbRight, Shift, P.X, P.Y);
              end;
              WM_MBUTTONDOWN: begin
                M.DoButtonDown(True, mbMiddle, Shift, P.X, P.Y);
              end;
              WM_MBUTTONUP: begin
                M.DoButtonDown(False, mbMiddle, Shift, P.X, P.Y);
              end;
              WM_MOUSEMOVE: begin
                M.DoMove(Shift, P.X, P.Y);
              end;
              WM_MOUSEWHEEL: begin
                //TODO
              end;
              WM_MOUSEHWHEEL: begin
                //TODO
              end;
            end;
          except
            on e: exception do begin
              //TODO
            end;
          end;
        end;
      except
        on e: exception do begin
          //TODO
        end;
      end;
    finally
      UnlockMouse;
    end;
  end;
  Result:= CallNextHookEx(_Hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
end;

{ TJDMouse }

constructor TJDMouse.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  LockMouse;
  try
    _Bucket.Add(Self); //Add self to bucket, registering to get events
  finally
    UnlockMouse;
  end;
end;

destructor TJDMouse.Destroy;
begin
  LockMouse;
  try
    _Bucket.Delete(_Bucket.IndexOf(Self)); //Remove self from bucket
  finally
    UnlockMouse;
  end;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TJDMouse.DoButtonDown(const IsDown: Boolean;
  const Button: TMouseButton; const Shift: TShiftState; const X, Y: Integer);
begin
  //Do not use lock, this is called from the lock already
  if IsDown then begin
    if assigned(FOnButtonDown) then
      FOnButtonDown(Self, Button, Shift, X, Y);
  end else begin
    if assigned(FOnButtonUp) then
      FOnButtonUp(Self, Button, Shift, X, Y);
  end;
end;

procedure TJDMouse.DoMove(const Shift: TShiftState; const X, Y: Integer);
begin
  //Do not use lock, this is called from the lock already
  if assigned(FOnMove) then
    FOnMove(Self, Shift, X, Y);
end;

function TJDMouse.GetCursorPos: TPoint;
begin
  LockMouse;
  try
    Result:= Controls.Mouse.CursorPos;
  finally
    UnlockMouse;
  end;
end;

procedure TJDMouse.SetCursorPos(const Value: TPoint);
begin
  LockMouse;
  try
    Controls.Mouse.CursorPos:= Value;
  finally
    UnlockMouse;
  end;
end;

initialization
  InitializeCriticalSection(_Lock);
  _Bucket:= TList.Create;
  _Hook:= SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, @LowLevelMouseProc, hInstance, 0);
finalization
  UnhookWindowsHookEx(_Hook);
  _Bucket.Free;
  DeleteCriticalSection(_Lock);
end.
```

And here's how it's implemented:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FMouse: TJDMouse;
    procedure MouseButtonDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure MouseButtonUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure MouseMoved(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
  end;

implementation

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FMouse:= TJDMouse.Create(nil);
  FMouse.OnButtonDown:= MouseButtonDown;
  FMouse.OnButtonUp:= MouseButtonUp;
  FMouse.OnMove:= MouseMoved;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FMouse.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.MouseButtonDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin

end;

procedure TForm1.MouseButtonUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin

end;

procedure TForm1.MouseMoved(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin

end;

end.
```

Comment: Well, theoretically, since it's a component, it's really intended to be dropped into a form designer and have its event handlers assigned that way.

Comment: Nice, instead of installing the hook in the the initialization section, Id'e install the hook only when _Bucket.Count==1 (TJDMouse.Create) and remove it when _Bucket is empty (TJDMouse.Destroy). and only in run-time not design mode.

Comment: @kobik Yes that is actually how my latest version works, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `TControlStyle.csCaptureMouse` flag if you're using VCL controls. I'm not sure if there is a FMX counterpart. [Relevant docs here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Vcl.Controls.TControlStyle).

I use `csCaptureMouse` in many of my custom controls and it works well.